# Fog distance significantly lower in 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So the fog distance in Minecraft 1.8 seems to be significantly closer than previous versions. I have the view distance set to maximum. Is there any way to extend the fog distance back to the old values?

Comment: You can try F3+F, which toggles fog distance.  I doubt it will work, though, if you're already at maximum.

Comment: Are you sure the fog setting hasn't simply returned to a lower default draw distance?

Comment: @raven Render Distance is "Far", a tunnel in one of my bases is all foggy now when this base was never foggy.

Comment: i wish that theyd make the fog optional for big builders such as myself...

Comment: Haven't tried this myself, but there's a mod that can be used to [remove void fog](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91544-181sep-15-lahwrans-mods-worldeditcui-polygons/).  This may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 1.8, the fog distance dynamically changes based on elevation.  When you're deep underground, the fog distance decreases, so even if it's set to "Far", you're still likely to see fog when exploring caves or walking through a long tunnel underground.

Comment: +1 I've noticed that along with the particle effect from the bedrock blocks, the near (and black) fog makes the very lowest layers much creepier now.

Comment: That answers that, although I really hate that change for my deep ocean base.

Comment: As a side note, if you have skylights that reach down to the lower levels, it'll keep the fog away.